# Why my buttons and my text box are not well aligned?

Tags: css, html

I have created a simple html file containing 2 buttons and one text box.

What I don't understand is that the height of my various elements is set equally to 20px for all elements, but they don't seem to be very well aligned (vertically). Even more frustrating, I was expecting my + and - buttons to be center aligned both on the vertical and the horizontal axis.

Do you have any idea what I have missed ?

[image]

Many thanks for your kind help.

Contents of 'form.html' :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<title>Form | 24ways.org</title>
<link rel=stylesheet href=style.css>
<script>
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="text" name="country" class="resizedTextbox" value="20" readonly>

<a href="#" class="myButton">+</a>
<a href="#" class="myButton">-</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Contents of 'style.css' :

```
.myButton {
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #54a3f7;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #54a3f7;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #54a3f7;
    background-color:#3e12cc;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
    border-radius:3px;
    border:1px solid #0815cc;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:18px;
    padding: 0 10px 10px 10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #154682;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
}
.myButton:hover {
    background-color:#0061a7;
}
.myButton:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
.resizedTextbox {width: 50px; 
height: 20px;
padding: 0 10px 10px 10px;
border-color:#3e12cc;
text-shadow:0px 1px 1px #154682;
background-color:#f5effb;
}
```

Comment: I had something similar recently, and setting `vertical-align` aligned them. But you have to experiment if only one of them needs it, or both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not accounting for the `2px` top and bottom border on the input field, add `2px` to the height of the buttons. https://jsfiddle.net/u8v3rgyt/4/

```
 .myButton {
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #54a3f7;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #54a3f7;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #54a3f7;
    background-color:#3e12cc;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
    border-radius:3px;
    border:1px solid #0815cc;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:18px;
    padding: 0 10px 10px 10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #154682;
    width:20px;
    height:22px;
}
```

Comment: Wonderful. One thousand thanks :)
Can I ask you how I could have the plus and the minus buttons vertically centered? Is there a possibility to achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

If you want vertical centering on the buttons (which are already using `display:inline-block;`), you can just use `vertical-align`. I do this all the time with buttons and icons. Just adjust as needed, i.e. `vertical-align:-1px`. You can use positive and negative values for `vertical-align`. You might need your input to have the same display. You could also try adding a margin to the top of the buttons. If that doesn't work, change the buttons to `display:block;`, use `float:left;`, and then add `margin-top`. Haven't tested but this is how I would approach it.